# Spring не подгружает сss

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Есть фронт-енд который отлично работает отдельно. Я вставляю его в свой Spring в папку views и при http направлении, на него с Контролера, вижу такое.
[image]

Tomcat, в первую очередь, загружает jsp где все написано без сss. К тому же, на нужной странице не работает навбар, кнопки просто не пускают на другие страницы, кроме тех, что Социальные.

Вот архитектура проэкта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема не в путях. Сайт работает без Spring.
Зависимости maven:spring-webmvc, spring-beans, spring-contex, spring-core, spring-web, thymeleaf-spring5

Не бейте

Comment: Ну а что сам браузер вам в консоль Dev Tools пишет?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () ... ykw.css:1